# Application error after using .aar file in my android studio sample project

Tags: java, android

I am learning android and found this extension really helpful in learning.

I have added an .aar file from project

https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

from the method i saw on youtube in my sample project, and thankfully did not get any error in complete  process.
But when I installed my sample app's apk on phone, it is force closing on all android versions (6.0 and 7.1.1 i have checked). It is giving

```
 Application Error - Unfortunately, the App has stopped
```

when I click on the picker which is perfectly seen on the screen.

But the issue is only country code picker is not coming on screen and application force closes.

Can you please help me with this.
I would be grateful to you.

I am assuming there is something issue in gradle. Don't know whether I am correct.

Here is the part which I have written in gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':ccp')
}
```

Comment: open logCat and copy the log please

Comment: hi. here is it https://pastebin.com/P5PhAEvx